# Symfony 3: How to use two choices/dropdowns from two tables in one form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Symfony version 3.1.3

I have created a dropdown using the entity called **Classes** and you can see the Controller below,

```
public function studentAddClassAction( $id, Request $request )
{
    // get the student from the student table
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user   = $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Users')->find($id);

    // new class object and create the form
    $classes= $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Classes')->findAll();
    $form   = $this->createForm(ClassType::class, $classes);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
    {
        // form submit operations
    }

    return $this->render(
                        'PIE10Bundle:student:layout_student_addclass.html.twig',
                        array(
                            'user'  => $user,
                            'title' => 'Add Class',
                            'tables'=> 1,
                            'form'  => $form->createView()
                        )
    );
}
```

and the **ClassType** is below

```
class ClassType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('classes',
                      EntityType::class,
                      array('class'     => 'PIE10Bundle:Classes',
                            'expanded'  => false,
                            'multiple'  => false,));
        $builder->add('Add Class',
                      SubmitType::class,
                      array('attr'  =>  array('class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                                              'style' => 'margin:15px 0;')) );
    }
}
```

And this works fine and it gives all the classes from the database. Also I have another entity called **Users** and it has a column called **roles** (DC2Type:array) and it has a role called `ROLE_PARENT` and I can retrieve all the parents using the following query

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM PIE10Bundle:Users u WHERE u.roles LIKE :role')
                    ->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_PARENT"%' );
$users = $query->getResult();
```

My Question is how to add these parents list as a choice list into same above form in the **studentAddClassAction** Controller.

Please let me know in any other information is needed for this.

Comment: Are `User` and `Classes` mapped by ManyToMany and you want in this form just to create a link between them? In other words, assign User to Class?

Comment: Yes I want to assign Class and Parents to the user and they going to be stored in a separate table called **students** it has three columns ClassID, ParentID and the UserID. So I want to add another choices list for Parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a custom set of entities as a choice list you need to use [a `query_builder` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder)

So it will look like

```
$builder->add('parent',
    EntityType::class,
    array('class'     => 'PIE10Bundle:Users',
        'expanded'  => false,
        'query_builder' =>  function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.roles LIKE :role')
                ->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_PARENT"%');
         },
         'multiple'  => false
));
```

Comment: Yes this works for me and also I have added the `'choice_label'  => 'username'` to avoid the listing userID in the options :))